# Adding object to List of base class

Tags: c#

having a base class :

```
public class BaseCommand {

}
```

and classes :

```
public class CommandA : BaseCommand  {

}
public class CommandB : BaseCommand  {

}
```

the list of BaseCommand :

```
 IList<BaseCommand> _Requests = new
                      List<BaseCommand>()
```

adding to this list can add any object that inherit from BaseCommand

but if there another class called Request :

```
public Request<T> where T : BaseCommand {
}
```

and a list of it :

```
IList<Request<BaseCommand>> _Requests = new
                      List<Request<BaseCommand>>();
```

we cannot add

```
 _Requests.Add(new Request<CommandA>());
```

can anyone explain this behavior and how we can solve it ? 
  thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

First off, it will help to know that the feature you're requesting has a name: generic type covariance.  C# supports covariance under the following situations:

- The type argument that is varying is a reference type on "both sides". That is, if we are trying to use an `IEnumerable<Tiger>` in a situation where `IEnumerable<Animal>` is expected, then both `Tiger` and `Animal` must be reference types.
- The generic type must be an interface or delegate type.
- The generic type must have been declared as covariant (or contravariant) by the author of the type, and the C# compiler must be able to *prove* that the type is safe for variance.

You've met the first condition for using variance but neither of the other necessary conditions, so you cannot use it.

Another way to look at it is: what could go wrong if C# had allowed you to do what you want?  Let's change `Request<T>` to `Cage<T>` and `BaseCommand` to `Animal`, just to make the relationships more clear:

```
abstract class Animal {}
class Tiger : Animal {}
class Giraffe : Animal {}
class Cage<T> where T : Animal 
{
  public T Contents { get; set; }
}
```

All right, now let's see what goes wrong:

```
List<Cage<Animal>> list = new List<Cage<Animal>>(); // Clearly this must be legal
list.Add(new Cage<Tiger>); // This is the step that you want to be legal.
Cage<Animal> cage = list[0]; // Clearly this must be legal; list[0] is a list element.
cage.Contents = new Giraffe(); // Clearly this is legal; a giraffe is an animal.
```

This program fragment has four lines, three of them have to be legal, and the result is a type error: there is now a giraffe in a tiger cage. Therefore the second line has to be illegal to prevent the type error, and it is.

You can solve the problem by making `Request` an interface which is safe for covariance:

```
interface IRequest<out T> where T : BaseCommand
// out T means make this type covariant in T
{
  T Command { get; }
  // T must appear in only *output* positions.
  // That is, no properties of type T with setters,
  // no methods that take a T as an input, and so on.
}
class Request<T> : IRequest<T> where T : BaseCommand
{  implement your class here }
... 

var list = new List<IRequest<BaseCommand>>();
list.Add(new Request<CommandA>(new CommandA()));
```

Now there is no problem. `Request<CommandA>` is convertible to `IRequest<CommandA>`, which is convertible covariantly to `IRequest<BaseCommand>` which can go in the list.

Unlike `Cage<T>`, `IRequest<T>` has no setter of type T, so there is no way to put a giraffe into a tiger cage anymore, so this is safe.

Comment: Rather a lot! Its a common problem and not immediately obvious why its unsafe.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `Cage<Fish>` (i.e., aquarium) over `Cage<Tiger>`.  My intuition screams a little bit more loudly when I drown a tiger in an aquarium than when I put a Giraffe in a tiger cage.  Though I suppose you've answered this question so many times that you prefer to vary it a bit.

Comment: Brian is correct. Why putting giraffe into a tiger cage is wrong? There is at most only one animal inside.

Comment: @Karol: Because the type system is supposed to guarantee that a property of a given type can only contain references to an object of that type; that's what *type safety* means. When you have a variable `c` of type `Cage<Tiger>` then you expect that `c.Contents` will also be of type `Tiger` and not `Octopus` or `Penguin`.